# Why do I get a build warning, saying: "data argument not used by format string"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have problem with this code   : 
I tried my best to solve but I failed , its build successfully but the warning annoying me very much .

```
// Parse content as structure (Atom feeds with element type="xhtml")
// - Use elementName not qualifiedName to ignore XML namespaces for XHTML entities
if (parseStructureAsContent) {

    // Open XHTML tag
    [currentText appendFormat:@"<%@", elementName];

    // Add attributes
    for (NSString *key in attributeDict) {
        [currentText appendFormat:@" %@=\"%@\"", key, 
            [[attributeDict objectForKey:key] stringByEncodingHTMLEntities]];
    }

    // End tag or close
    if (ELEMENT_IS_EMPTY(elementName)) {
        [currentText appendFormat:@" />", elementName];
    } else {
        [currentText appendFormat:@">", elementName];
    }
```

the problem is in last lines

```
    if (ELEMENT_IS_EMPTY(elementName)) {
        [currentText appendFormat:@" />", elementName];
    } else {
    [currentText appendFormat:@">", elementName];
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Or what is the annoying warning message about?

Comment: @Hermann Klecker The warning message was hidden in the question's title. Did an edit.

Comment: Ah, yes. That is because the data argument (elementName) was not used by the format string (@">").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the warning says, there is no placeholder for the argument `elementName` in the line below.

```
[currentText appendFormat:@" />", elementName];
```

Just do `[currentText appendFormat:@" />"];`